# What is an "Otik Style" nymph?

Tags: story-identification, terminology

Under "Unanswered" questions, in July, Tark described a wonderful story I'd like to see too.

Tark describes it as "[Wood nymph (otik style) who becomes a scientist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38345/wood-nymph-otik-style-who-becomes-a-scientist)"

What does "otik style" mean?

(I'm too new to ask under that post)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Otik

Comment: It probably means that it was a piece of wood with human features, like Little Otik, and not a classical [nymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph) (magical aethereal beautiful young woman).

Answer (score 3):

As @R. Skeeter suggested in a comment, it's probably a reference to the movie [Little Otik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Otik), based on a fairy tale in which a couple adopt a tree stump that comes to life (so, sort of a similar idea to a wood nymph).

Comment: I *did* find that movie in trying to answer my question myself, but Tark's description of the nymph sounds sociable and pleasant. He goes to parties and ultimately becomes a great thinker...The stump baby in "Little Otik" is described as a man-eating shut-in, with a morbid, pedophilia-stalked child as his keeper/enabler.